# How to delay an execution when using a timer in C#

Tags: c#, timer

I'm using timer to capture an Image from a camera.
I'm doing some processing on this capture Image and detect a point on this image and pass that point to a robot. Before passing that point I have to wait for some variable time. At the moment I use Thread.sleep(waitingTime). But this will make my UI to unrespond for a certain time. How can I make a delay in my code?

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image<Bgr, Byte> imSource = cap.RetrieveBgrFrame();

    //some processing here
    //--------------------
    //--------------------

    Thread.Sleep(waitingTime);
    sendToRobot(data);
}
```

Comment: why you need the delay ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{

    Thread.Sleep(waitingTime);
    sendToRobot(data);
 });
```

This should work as long as sendToRobot updates the UI carefully using the correct thread.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try  Task. Delay ( [delayperiod]);